# Correlation with one variable and a lot of others

Tags: stata

In Stata, is there a quick way to show the correlation between a variable and a bunch of dummies. In my data I have an independent variable, `goals_scored` in a game, and a bunch of dummies for `stadium` played. How can I show the correlation between the `goals_scored` and `i.stadium` in one table, without getting the correlations between stadiums, which I do not care about.

Comment: Do you just want to know whether some stadiums have systematically higher goal scored?

Comment: I'd be tempted to try a poisson regression: poisson goals_scored i.stadium, nocons robust. The exponentiated parameters (i.e., e^b) will tell you the expected number of goals for a match in that stadium. You might ask this as a separate question on the crossvalidated site. Make sure to describe your data more precisely (maybe post a few example rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#delimit;    

quietly tab stadium, gen(D); // create dummies

foreach var of varlist D* {;    
  quietly corr goals_scored `var';
  di as text "`: variable label `var'':   " as result r(rho);
};

drop D*; // get rid of dummies
```

Answer (score 1):

`cpcorr` from SSC (install with `ssc inst cpcorr`) supports minimal correlation tables, i.e. only the correlations between one set and another set, without the others. But it's an old program (2001) and doesn't support factor variables directly. The indicator variables (a.k.a. dummy variables) would have to exist first.

Comment: I don't understand the reply. You wanted a quick way to calculate the correlations and `cpcorr` is one. Internally it's a loop over variables, inevitably, so this answer is similar to others. By the way, there are now open suggestions and questions on several threads you have opened recently. Good protocol is that you close threads by accepting an answer or by explaining why a reply is wrong or otherwise not what you want. I am down-voting your question. It's turned into: What do you propose?, too general a question to be answered on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you store all of the stadium variables in a local, you would probably loop through them to pull the correlations.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without listing each variable? I have over 100 stadiums.

Comment: Do they have a similar naming convention? Then you could use wildcards, something like "stadium_*" for stadium_1, stadium_2, stadium_3...etc.

Comment: Or, if you know all of the variables are right next to each other in the dataset, you can specify the column number range, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

1.
If all stadium variables are placed next to each other in the dataset:

```
foreach s of varlist stadium1-stadium150 {
    // do whatever
}
```

2a.
If the stadium variables are not next to each other, use `order` to get there.

2b.
If the variable names follow a pattern, there might be another workaround.

3.
I would not use correlation for this. Depending on the distribution of goals, I would consider something else.

Comment: I am just looking how the goals vary with stadium. What would you propose?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the distribution of goals before coding anything further! I am afraid Nick is right: the technical answer is already out there (and it's impossible for us to know which answer is best without looking at your data), and there's a more general issue in your question that should go to CrossValidated.